# Api only accessible from trusted sites not by any browser, postman & etc

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, request, cross-domain

It is possible to make API only response to specific request?

Example I have API on `http://api.example.test`

And I don't want anybody get access to it by simply using web browser and put that url, or using postman to perform any POST request, or any other thing.

I want the api only can be access by specific site example `http://example.test`

This will work like this:

`http://example.test` is like admin panel that control all other thing to that api

`http://api.example.test` just a api database to store all information. No front-end on this site.

The api use **Laravel**, and has CORS apply to allow only for whitelist domain. But this doesn't prevent from any direct request or postman & etc.

If there's any source where can I read about this, or any explanation. I'm really appreciate it

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incoming traffic is blocked or allowed by server configs rather than from the codebase of the app itself (tl;dr, this has nothing to do with Laravel).
By configuring virtual hosts on your Apache2, for example, or by modifying security group of your EC2 instance (on AWS), you can specifically whitelist, blacklist certain IPs from accessing your location.

This is what an Apache Virtual host looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.net
DocumentRoot /public

<Directory "/public">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.10.10.10
    Allow from 10.10.11.0/24
</Directory>
```